# If minimal degree is at least $k$, then the graph contians a path of length at least $k$

Tags: inequality, graph-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

$G$ is a simple graph that consists of a vertex set $V(G) = \{v_1, v_2, ..., v_n\}$ and an edge set $E(G) = \{e_1, e_2, ..., e_m\}$ where each edge is an ordered pair of vertices. The edge $\{u,v\}$ is denoted $uv$.  A walk of length $k$ is a sequence $v_0,e_1,v_1,e_2,...,e_k,v_k$ of vertices and edges such that $e_i=v_{i-1}v_i$ for all $i$. A path is a walk with no repeated vertex.

Prove:  If $G$ is a finite simple graph in which every vertex has degree at least $k$, then $G$ contains a path of length at least $k$.

I believe this has something to do with the longest path but I can't come up with a reasoning/proof that is of length of at least $k$.

Comment: As well as my answer, there is a constructive answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1330488/prove-theres-a-simple-path-of-length-k-in-a-simple-graph-g-where-all-the-ve?rq=1