# Connectivity and minimum length

Tags: proof-verification, graph-theory, graph-connectivity

Prove that a simple graph G is 2-connected if and only if for every triple (x, y, z)
of distinct vertices, G has an x, z-path through y

Thanks!

Comment: Why must there be $k$ vertices with degree $\ge 2$? What's the argument for that? And why would the existence of such a path of length $k$ follow from that?

Comment: Suppose $\delta(G) <k$ and pick (one of) the vertex that has degree $< k$. Then remove all of its neighbors. The vertex is now isolated.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma there must be $k$ vertices with degree $\geq 2$, because if we assume there are $k-1$ vertices  with degree $\geq 2$, then it is necessary the removal of at most $k-2$ vertices in order for G to become either disconnected or $K_1$. But that is a contradiction on the assumption $G$ is $k$-connected.

Comment: @user1944 Sorry for the confusion, maybe you should write it in your question. (Note that [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory)) is on my side :-P )

Comment: $\delta(G)$ can't possibly mean the shortest path (which is $0$ for any graph). It also can't mean the diameter of $G$ since $K_{k + 1}$ is $k$-connected and has diameter $1$.

Comment: Your statement is the definition of $k$-connected, essentially.

Comment: @TrevorGunn I've fixed. I think it is correct what I mean now. Thanks alot.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I've fixed it. I think it is correct now. Did you see my explanation as to why there must be k vertices with degree >= 2?

Comment: @Zubzub you are right. I made a mistake writing the problem. Thanks!

Comment: The accepted practice around here is to write the problem statement in the body of the question, not just the title.

Comment: If there are only $k-1$ vertices of degree $\ge 2$, which $k$ vertices do you remove to get a contradiction with $G$ being $k$-connected?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma  $v_1,v_2,...,v_{k-1}$?

Comment: And those are? You haven’t introduced them.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma vertices whose degree is at least 2 ?

Comment: And why is the remaining graph disconnected?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma because they all have degree equal to 1

Comment: That is not true, necessarily.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma If I deleted all vertices whose degree is at least 2, only the vertices whose degree is 1 remained. Since we are assuming G connected, the remaining must be disconnected.. right?

Comment: Even having $k$ many points of degree $\ge 2$ does not garantuee a path as claimed. It buys you nothing, by itself.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma That I know. There is a huge discussion below, a really nice guy explaining that to me, but I get it now. Thanks for your help and patience, too!

Answer (score 3):

Never forget the contraposition!

If a longest path $P$ in $G$ has length $k-1$, then $G$ is not $k$-connected.

Proof: Let $v$ be the starting vertex of $P$. Then there is no edge joining $v$ and a vertex that's not in $P$. Hence, $deg(v)<k$. Hence, $G$ is not $k$-connected.

Answer (score 1):

The implication from there are $k$ vertices with degree at least $2$ to there is a path of length $k$ does not hold. For a counterexample, consider 3 triangles glued together at a common vertex. There are 7 vertices, each with degree at least 2, but the longest path is just 5 vertices long.

Instead, I would think of the problem along these lines. Let $v_1 \sim v_2 \sim \dots \sim v_m$ be a path in $G$. If $m < k$, we can delete $v_1,\dots,v_{m-1}$ from $G$ and get a connected graph. Which means that $v_m \sim w$ for some $w$ not appearing earlier in the path. So the longest path has to have length at least $k$.

If you want to use your idea, you can replace "there are $k$ vertices with degree at least $2$" with "*every* vertex has degree at least $k$" as in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1330488/prove-theres-a-simple-path-of-length-k-in-a-simple-graph-g-where-all-the-ve) question.

Comment: But I am assuming that G is $k$-connected. In your example, G is 1-connected, that is to say, just deleting the common vertex already disconnects G.

Comment: What you have is a chain of implications "G is k-connected" implies that "G has k vertices with degree at least 2" implies "G has a path of length k". The second implication is false. It is true that if "G is k-connected" *and* "G has k vertices with degree at least 2" then "G has a path of length k" but this is only because "G is k-connected"  implies "G has a path of length k" having nothing to do with whether or not "G k vertices with degree at least 2".

Comment: @user1944 If you have a theorem of the form $P \implies Q$. You can prove it by a sequence of implications: $P \implies P_1 \implies P_2 \cdots \implies Q$. If one of your implications is false, it's not a proof, even though $P \implies Q$ is a theorem (is true).

Comment: But you still haven't given me a counter example to show that "G is k-connected" implies that "G has k vertices with degree at least 2" is not true.

Comment: @user1944 That implication is true, the second is not.

Comment: so $P\implies P_1$ is correct, but using this to imply $P_2$ is not?

Comment: @user1944 Your proof has the form $A \implies B \implies C$ where $A \implies B$ is correct, $A \implies C$ is correct but $B \implies C$ is not correct.

Comment: I finally see what you mean. A chain of implications is not the same as "and" (obviously). So one way to force $A\land B \implies C$ is by using your suggestion: every vertex has degree at least $k$. This means G has $nk/2$ edges. Since G is simple, there must be a path with length $nk/2 \geq k$ for $n>1$. Is it good now?

Comment: @user1944 No because having a lot of edges doesn't mean you have a path of that length. For instance, if $k = 4$ and every vertex has degree $4$, then there are twice as many edges as vertices but since a path can't reuse vertices, you can't have a path whose length exceeds the number of vertices available.

Comment: could you give a counter example? cuz if $G$ is simple and $k$-connected, then it must have at least $k-1$ vertices.

Comment: @user1944 Take $K_n$. Since $K_n$ is $k = n - 1$-connected, every vertex has degree at least $k$. Therefore $K_n$ has at least $nk/2$ edges. But there is no path of length $nk/2$ for $n \ge 4$ since the longest path has length $n$ and $nk/2 > n$ when $k = n - 1 \ge 3$.

Comment: I can't think of a solution using my strategy. Do you have a hint? You solution is much simpler, by the way.

Comment: @user1944 I put a link to a question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1330488/ at the end of the last paragraph. To show that every vertex has degree at least $k$ you do what Zubzub said.

Comment: I completely understand it now. Thank you very much for your patience. I've learned a lot today!